# How to redirect URL in Jsoup?

Tags: jsoup

i have this code:

```
int pageNum = 1;
        List<String> urlLink = new ArrayList<String>();
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://secret-site?pagenum=" + pageNum).followRedirects(true).userAgent("Chrome/51.0.2704.103").timeout(0)
                .get();
        Elements links = doc.select("td[align] .midtext > a");
        for(Element e : links) {
            if (e.attr("href").contains("title_about")) {
                urlLink.add(e.attr("href"));
                }
                if(urlLink.size()%100==0) {
                    pageNum++;
                    // how to redirect doc?
                }
                if (pageNum==3) {
                    break;
                }
            }
```

how to make that would be in the condition where pagenum incremented page has been updated?

sorry for my English.

Comment: redirect to which `doc` ? are you trying to redirect your program to `Document doc = Jsoup.connect....` this line ?

Comment: yes, i have http://secret-site?pagenum=1, when jsoup scraping all the links me need to go to the http://secret-site?pagenum=2

Comment: so basically whenever your condition `urlLink.size()%100==0` is true you want to execute the programm from start?

Comment: when urlLink.size()%100==0 need redirect secret-site?pagenum=2(because pageNum incremented) and 
start parsing again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When changing the pagenum value in the url, you are changing the [GET](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/ref_httpmethods.asp) parameter for a request, so you have to request the result page for the new request by calling `Jsoup.connect(...).get()` again.
You could change the url-string ("http://secret-site?pagenum=2"), but I find it more readable using the [`.data("key","value")`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Connection.html#data-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) method.
Surround your code with a loop to increment the pagenum value and you are done.

**Example code**

```
String userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.116 Safari/537.36";
int numberOfResultpages = 3;
String url = "http://secret-site";

List<String> urlLink = new ArrayList<String>();

Document doc;

for (int i = 1; i < numberOfResultpages; i++) {

    try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent(userAgent)
                .data("pagenum", "" + i)
                .method(Method.GET).get();

        for (Element e : doc.select("td[align] .midtext > a")) {

            if (!e.attr("href").contains("title_about"))
                continue;

            urlLink.add(e.attr("href"));

            if(urlLink.size()%100==0) {
                break;
            }
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```